# codeigniter calling show_error from a library

Tags: codeigniter

I can't manage to call show_error from inside a library file I get

Warning: include(application/errors/error_php.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\project\SOURCE\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 167

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you need to create a CI instance?

> To access CodeIgniter's native resources within your library use the get_instance() function. This function returns the CodeIgniter super object.

more [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

So perhaps something like

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->show_error('something is not right here . . . ');
```

Will do what you want.